# Function keys are not working on HP Compaq NC6220

Tags: keyboard, drivers

The Function keys are not working on my HP Compaq NC6220.

I have Installed QLB from the HP website but same problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Some HP notebooks have a [bios setting for the Fn key](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02035108&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN), you might look in the bios to see if they are disabled.

Which OS is installed?

Comment: Windows XP Home Installed, and I have checked the BIOS setup and I didnt find any option for the function enable keys.

Comment: Some HP models use a keyboard filter driver to enable Fn special functions, which is not available for download unfortunately.